# Using set identities, prove that $\overline A \cup \overline B \cup (A \cap B \cap \overline C)= \overline A \cup \overline B \cup \overline C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, discrete-calculus

I tried solving the problem but I get $U \cap U$ Which indeed $ \overline A \cup \overline B \cup \overline C$

Unfortunately I'm having a hard time proving it, any help?

Comment: If you use distributivity, you should get $(\overline A\cup\overline B\cup A)\cap(\overline A\cup\overline B\cup B)\cap(\overline A\cup\overline B\cup\overline C)=U\cap U\cap(\overline A\cup\overline B\cup\overline C)=\overline A\cup\overline B\cup\overline C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use distributivity, note that:

$$\overline A \cup \overline B \cup (A \cap B \cap \overline C)= \overline A \cup \left[(\overline B \cup A)\cap(\overline B\cup B)\cap(\overline B\cup \overline C)\right].$$

Since obviously $\overline B\cup B=1$, then it equals

$$\overline A\cup\left[(\overline B \cup A)\cap(\overline B \cup \overline C)\right],$$

and using again distributivity:

$$\left[(\overline A \cup \overline B)\cup (\overline A \cup A)\right]\cap\left[(\overline A\cup \overline B)\cup(\overline A\cup\overline C)\right] =$$
$$= 1\cap (\overline A\cup \overline B \cup \overline C)=\boxed{\overline A\cup \overline B\cup \overline C}$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $X=\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$. Then from De Morgan's law you know that
$$
\overline{X}=A\cap B
$$
so your left-hand side becomes
$$
X\cup(\overline{X}\cap\overline{C})=(X\cup\overline{X})\cap(X\cup\overline{C})=X\cup\overline{C}
$$